# What is the difference between these lines of code?

Tags: java

I'm learning to code in Java and I'm doing some online exercises where the answer is not explained too much, so I was just curious why my code is incorrect when it seems to be similar to the solution.

The exercise says -

"Given 2 int values, return true if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative."

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)) {
  return true;
  }

return (a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0);

} // This is my code that yields unwanted results

public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (negative) {
    return (a < 0 && b < 0);
  }
  else {
    return ((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0));
  }
} // This is the solution code
```

When running posNeg(-4, 5, true); it comes out to be true even though it is supposed to be false. Whenever one int is negative and the other is positive and negative is true, it is supposed to be false but yields true.

Comment: Did you try tracing the execution of your code for this example?

Comment: which method gives you that result?

Comment: Your first condition is false so it executes the next one and `a < 0 && b > 0` is true so the method returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {
  if (negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)) {
    return true;
  }

  return (a < 0 && b > 0 || a > 0 && b < 0);

} // This is my code that yields unwanted results
```

Calling `posNeg(-4, 5, true);` makes the first condition false `negative && (a < 0 && b < 0)` <===> true && (true && false) <===> false.
Then the run jumps to the end of that `if` and evaluates the last condition `(a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)` which is obviously true.